# Can I undo a domain level 301 redirect? It's causing a slight traffic drop

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

I have recently set up a redirect from an aged domain to a live domain using a 301 redirect. I created an acquisition press release on the live site and the old domain (which I built a home page for and is indexed in Google). Then implemented a 301 redirect to the aged domain to the live acquisition page

`ageddomain.com > 301 > livedomain.com/acquisition_page`

I also implemented a series of around 5 page to page 301 redirects for relevant topics, including

```
product page > 301 > product page
about us > 301 > about us
etc
```

This seems to be causing a slight loss in traffic, and some keywords have dropped out of the Google index.

So my question is two parts:

1. Is this normal to see this wobbly or slight decline in traffic?
2. Should I attempt to remove all of the 301 redirects and rethink? If so will it recover, or will it do more harm than good?

Any advice gratefully received

Comment: How much time has passed and how old is the new site? The livedomian.example.com needs some time before it is fully E-A-T evaluated. While the aged.example.com may have some E-A-T boost. Is there any low-hanging fruit, which a new page could be created with unique content so that the new content on live.domain.com could be natively pick up by the new content; And, Google could rank it for something while it evaluates the new domain? So the AI can determine the new domain is desirable by Google's visitors.

Comment: Just noticed the question is 30 days old, (I'm slow this morning), what is now being seen? I would expect 30 days is enough but different verticals have different amounts of Google interest ...

Answer (score 1):

If the 301 redirects are working as they are supposed to you should leave them alone.

Whenever you do a redirect you may loose a bit of Google juice - that is normal.   Once Google has your target paged index its probably better to leave it and hopefully let it build up credibility.

Be aware that Googles algorythm is changing quite a lot, and stuff often is just not ranking as well (because Google prefers itself and paid snippets).  It is not uncommon to see pages no longer being deindexed by Google at the moment (although generally this is with poorer ranking pages or pages with spammy backlinks or AI generated content)